# How to update progressbar in a ListView item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar, android-download-manager

I have a `ListView` attached to an `ArrayAdapter`. When the user clicks a download button for an item in the `ListView` a download starts using the `DownloadManager`.

What I want to do is to track the download progress with a progress bar (placed in the item layout). How can this be achieved?

The way Pocket Cast does it is exacly what I'm after:

[Pocket Cast exampel http://www.mrcrab.net/images/thumb_big/9982-Pocket_Casts_Apk_v4.3.2_Android-0.jpg](http://www.mrcrab.net/images/thumb_big/9982-Pocket_Casts_Apk_v4.3.2_Android-0.jpg)

*Note: I know how to work with the `DownloadManager`, it's the instant update of the progress bar that is tricky.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the way I finally solved it (after many iterations and different implementations). It's a bit tricky but basically you need three things:

1. An AsyncTask that gathers meta data
2. A scroll listener that tells us when the user has stopped scrolling/flinging
3. A clever algorithm that finds any visible row that needs updating and asks the adapter to only update that specific row

This is the way I designed and implemented it:

[image: Screenshot]

I wrote in more detail about [it here](http://slidese.github.io/slidese/2013/11/25/update_listview_item.html), and please see the [github code](https://github.com/slidese/SGU/blob/3be1888115ba56b4a015b127b249c35af5dc11d0/src/se/slide/sgu/ContentFragment.java) for the complete imlementation.

```
    private class UpdaterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    boolean isRunning = true;

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while (isRunning) {

            // Gather data about your adapter objects
            // If an object has changed, mark it as dirty                

            publishProgress();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        super.onProgressUpdate();

        // Update only when we're not scrolling, and only for visible views
        if (mScrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            int start = mListview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            for(int i = start, j = mListview.getLastVisiblePosition(); i<=j; i++) {
                View view = mListview.getChildAt(i-start);
                if (((Content)mListview.getItemAtPosition(i)).dirty) {
                    mListview.getAdapter().getView(i, view, mListview); // Tell the adapter to update this view
                }

            }
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I try to make it but I have a pb. When I press BackButton, the dl continues (that's what I want) but when I get back in this view, progressBars don't move. Can you put an example of your adapter. Does it works like me when you press back and return to same view ?

Comment: Yes, it works when the `Activity` starts as well as when it resumes activity (from a paused state). Have a look at `private void refreshScreen()` in the source code here: https://github.com/slidese/SGU/blob/master/src/se/slide/sgu/StartActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

For a specific view item, you can retrieve it using [getChildAt(int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) and update it.

And you can traverse through all visible items by the help of [getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) and [getLastVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29)

Comment: But how do you know if a specific view is in a downloadable state? I assume you would have an `AsyncTask` that would query the `DownloadManager`, so you're left with 0 or more download IDs but have no idea what `ListView` items these correspond to. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: With download IDs, you can have URIs (either by asking DownloadManager or your own map that matches a download ID with a URI).
From a `ListView` position, you can get the URI from your adapter.
So now, you have a link between download ID and `ListView` position.

Comment: Or you can even have a map that stores download IDs and `ListView` positions. That map can be manipulated when you enqueue a request with the `DownloadManager`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might work. Will try an implementation later tonight.

Comment: And please share any news :)

Comment: Just posted the way I finally implemented it. You were correct to use the methods you mentioned but it was just a small part of the total implementation I felt a more complete answer was needed. Hope you're ok with that @huy.nguyen