# How make multiple files download manager with a progress bar in ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar, android-download-manager

Iam new in android 
i need to make a dynamic file(.mp3,.mp4) download manager for my app in this form :

- adding new link to current list
- can pause and resume download
- the whole action can be progress in background
- deleting complete downloads from custom list
- it's user threads and asynk
- when i close the app,the list not be erase

I had followed these links but they are not usefull to me: 
- [Multiple file download manager in listview +progress/pause/resume android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720624/multiple-file-download-manager-in-listview-progress-pause-resume-android)

- [Download multiple files with a progress bar in ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875838/download-multiple-files-with-a-progress-bar-in-listview-android)

most of the links and tutorial not work or not even published because of errors,i will be so thankfull to guide me with full source code of this download manager.
i thought it's be better to call a function like this "SomeFunction(url)",then it's manager the download and link.
please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function to update the list view item

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use DownloadManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Examples:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-downloadmanager-example.html

http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/

[Android download manager completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477493/android-download-manager-completed)

Comment: tanks,but i saw all these and do,but my main problem to get these together